# Azure alert when SQL firewall rule added

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to get an alert when a [firewall rule is added to an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal)? I checked the monitoring blade and didn't see a metric or log event for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a logic app to achieve that:

1. Create a new logic app using "When a HTTP request is received" template. Use the following JSON as your sample payload. Then you will need to add a condition and an action (email?). In email body you can send more details like caller email, caller ip, etc.

Conditions should be Status=Activated and OperationName="Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules/write".
[image]
 2. create a new alert in Monitor. The resource will be your SQL Server and the signal will be "All Administrative operations".
Create a new action group and set an webhook action. Use the logic app webhook url generate in the previous step.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Expect": "100-continue",
        "Host": "abc.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "IcMBroadcaster/1.0",
        "X-CorrelationContext": "abc",
        "Content-Length": "1350",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "schemaId": "Microsoft.Insights/activityLogs",
        "data": {
            "status": "Activated",
            "context": {
                "activityLog": {
                    "channels": "Operation",
                    "eventSource": "Administrative",
                    "eventTimestamp": "2019-03-09T10:00:36.549+00:00",
                    "eventDataId": "eventid",
                    "level": "Informational",
                    "operationName": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules/write",
                    "properties": {
                        "originalEventTimestamp": "03/09/2019 10:00:17",
                        "correlationId": "correlationId",
                        "eventId": "eventId",
                        "eventName": "OverwriteFirewallRules",
                        "operationName": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules/write",
                        "status": "Succeeded",
                        "description_scrubbed": "description",
                        "caller": "useremail@email.com",
                        "callerCredentialType": "LiveId",
                        "eventChannel": "OperationLogStore",
                        "ipAddress": "useripaddress",
                        "eventSource": "SQL Databases Event Supplier"
                    },
                    "resourceId": "resourceId",
                    "resourceGroupName": "groupname",
                    "resourceProviderName": "MICROSOFT.SQL",
                    "status": "Succeeded",
                    "subscriptionId": "subscriptionId",
                    "submissionTimestamp": "2019-03-09T10:00:36.549+00:00",
                    "resourceType": "microsoft.sql/servers"
                }
            },
            "properties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice dude, creative solution!

Comment: But where is the http request coming from?

Comment: Explained in the 2nd step.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Activity Log. If you add a new firewall rule and check the Activity Log after a few minutes you'll see a series of entries with the operation name **Update SQL server firewall rules**. Click on the one with a status of **Succeeded**.  The next page will have a **New alert rule** button.

You'll need to edit the condition as it sets the initiator to your username.  To do this, click the condition and change the **Event Initiated by** value.